# How to display my react application as desktop view on mobile?

Tags: reactjs, web, responsive-design, frontend, web-frontend

I know I can use media query in order to make the design responsive. but I do not want to do that now. what I would like to do is when the user load the app on mobile, my react app detects that and display the app as desktop view on mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the meta link in the `index.html` to display a desktop version:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1920">
```

Instead of the responsive version which is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

you will find `index.html` in the public folder

Comment: thank you @adarsh it is working, I wan wondering if this way has any disadvantages.

Comment: the only disadvantage i can think of is now all the pages will get desktop view in mobile. if you don't want that you can pass this modified meta tag using the react-helmet package